# TLS-PSK via Vert.x

Tags: java, tls1.2, vert.x, tls-psk

I am trying to connect from my verticle to device that implement TLS-PSK encryption algorithm TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA and protocol "TLSv1.2". I have an example of code where we use BouncyCastle library for communicate.

```
TlsPSKIdentity pskIdentity = new BasicTlsPSKIdentity("identity", Hex.decode("/*psk key*/d901308ef9c6997fabf3a88d80954e17ecfef43f5ad9a1fc780fdd07e5494ae6"));
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        Socket socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("some host"), 12345);
        SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
        MockPSKTlsClient client = new MockPSKTlsClient(null, pskIdentity);
        TlsClientProtocol protocol = new TlsClientProtocol(
                socket.getInputStream(),
                socket.getOutputStream(),
                secureRandom
        );

        protocol.connect(client);

        OutputStream output = protocol.getOutputStream();
        output.write("someMessage".getBytes("UTF-8"));

        InputStream input = protocol.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(">>> " + line);
        }

        output.close();
        input.close();
        socket.close();
        protocol.close();
```

I know that Vert.x Ssl options can be configured in keystore/trustore format.
My task is to implement this in Vert.x. Can anybody help me understand how can I get successful connection with PSK and vertx NetClient?